# Win32 - Image Lists in ListView

Tags: image, winapi, listview, resources

I am trying to add images to a listview. I have saved an image that is 32x16 and attempting to use ImageList_Add() to split it into 2 images ( since it should be able to infer the number of images from the width ). The items are being added but without images. There appears to be something there when I click but not the images nor the sizes I expect.

I am using the following code:

```
LVCOLUMN lvc = {0};
lvc.mask     = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH;
lvc.pszText  = _T("Some column header");
lvc.cx       = 150;

HWND hwndListView = GetDlgItem( hwndDlg, IDC_LISTVIEW );
ListView_InsertColumn( hwndListView, 0, &lvc );

HIMAGELIST hImageList = ImageList_Create( 16, 16, ILC_COLOR, 2, 0 );
HBITMAP    hbmBlobs   = ( HBITMAP )LoadImage( ( HINSTANCE )lParam,
  MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDB_BLOBS ), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, 0 );

ImageList_Add( hImageList, hbmBlobs, NULL );
DeleteObject( hbmBlobs );
ListView_SetImageList( hwndListView, hImageList, LVSIL_SMALL );
ImageList_Destroy( hImageList );

LVITEM lvi = {0};
lvi.mask   = LVIF_IMAGE;
lvi.iImage = 0;
ListView_InsertItem( hwndListView, &lvi );

lvi.iImage = 1;
ListView_InsertItem( hwndListView, &lvi );
```

I have uploaded skeleton code that does the bare minimum to create the ListView and my attempt at making the images display. Thank you for your time.

http://localhostr.com/file/adUSZvF/Skeleton.rar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call ImageList_Destroy on the imagelist! A listview without the [LVS_SHAREIMAGELISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) style will destroy the imagelist for you...

Comment: Thanks Anders. I must have misunderstood the documentation. Moving that line to WM_CLOSE results in a dialogue that acts as expected !